# Calling a method from a system service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, reflection, android-service

There are system and custom services in Android that cannot be referenced from Android Studio. Lets say, I want to call a getFlashLockState() method from a PersistentDataBlockManager service. Default approach is to add a service reference.

```
import android.service.persistentdata.PersistentDataBlockManager;
```

Writing the following line to the code will result in an error: Android Studio cannot resolve the symbol "PersistentDataBlockManager", as its default

> android.service.*

does not contain a reference to persistentdata service. I tried using reflection to get the class by name and was able to get a reference like this:

```
Class<?> referenceClass = Class.forName("android.service.persistentdata.PersistentDataBlockManager");
Object referenceObject = referenceClass.newInstance();
```

But instantiating an object threw an error: the class has no zero argument constructor. After checking its [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/1c4d535d0806dbeb6d2fa5cea0373cbd9ab6d33b/core/java/android/service/persistentdata/PersistentDataBlockManager.java) I found out that its only constructor looks like this:

```
public PersistentDataBlockManager(IPersistentDataBlockService service)
```

Basically, it turned out to be only a wrapper that accepts an actual implementation of a class from a system library. I also tried using other kinds of reflections like:

```
context.getSystemService()
```

to get an actual reference of a running service, but none of them worked for me, as the class is not static and I cant find a way to get its instance.

Is there a reliable way to call a non-static method from a non-default system service?

Comment: *Is there a reliable way to call a non-static method from a non-default system service?* - **[No](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces)**

Comment: There is no requirement for an arbitrary Android device to have any classes that are not part of the SDK. Some device manufacturer might remove, rename, repackage, or otherwise modify `PersistentDataBlockManager`, `IPersistentDataBlockService`, etc. If it involves reflection, by definition, it is not reliable. Plus, Android 9.0+ is starting to block this sort of reflection-based access.

Comment: Is there any way to call this service? Lets say I am writing an app for an exact phone model.

Comment: You can do this, but you need to generate a jar with all stub of your framework. So you can plug this jar to your app and invoke framework methods